# Page length exceeded

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, templates

I am writing a paper for a journal and by the time I try to build a pdf version, I realized the length of each page is shifted down. Here I attached a snapshot an here is a [link](https://files.fm/u/hb9b55kn) to the **Journal's** latex template.

[image: Photo]

**EDIT**

Please after downloading the latex format from link, add this preamble and run it with a random textual content. It may get reproduced as shown in the attached figure.

```
    \documentclass[color,twoside,amssymb,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{Latex-document}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}

%\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1,1,1}
%\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.052, 0.25, 1}



%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
%
%\setcounter{subsection}{0}

%%%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\newcommand{\titlename}{$\bm{Frontiers~ of~ Computer~ Science~ in~ China}$\\[2mm] {\bf Instruction for authors}}
\newcommand{\authorname}{First name, LAST NAME$^{1,2}$}
\newcommand{\atime}{Received month dd.yyyy; accepted month dd.yyyy}
\newcommand{\aemail}{$\times\times\times\times@\times\times\times.\times\times\times$}
```

Comment: please don't use external links, the question and any answer are archived here forever and won't make sense if any text at that link changes. (Also many readers wouldn't follow links to an unknown site)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have no other way to include the latex format as you have to sing up to the journal to get an access to the latex/Word format.

Comment: @lonesome the idea of this site is that you take a copy of your document, delete everything not relevant to the issue and end up with a small one or two page example that you can post inline to your question. It's not reasonable to expect people to download an entire full size document archive from some ad filled download site and debug the issue from there. You have the document showing the problem so you can do the initial work to narrow down the test example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sir, I guess you are not listening to me. This is a journal format. How am I supposed to pass its latex class???

Comment: Either you are allowed to post it here or you probably are not allowed to post it to that download site, but anyway it is up to you, I certainly would not download that archive so I can't debug your question sorry.